# Error when using Java String split

Tags: java, regex

HI All,

I've been using the basic split for a while - where I just parse out a string into an array based on a simple token like " " or ",".

So of course a customer tries this: `\\.br\`  which fails miserably.

I need to parse to an array of lines. The string for example looks like this:

`"LINE 1\\.br\\LINE 2\\.br\\LINE 3\\.br\\LINE 4\\.br\\"`

and this fails with `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error`.

Any ideas?

Comment: show us the code you are failing.  also you still can use `indexOf("\\.br\\")` and loop over it

Comment: I think it was added randomly. I didn't chose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget [String.split takes a Regex](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), and most people put in a string literal, so you have to escape the \ for regex **and** escape it for strings, so you end up with "\\\" in your String argument to represent a single \ character.

e.g.

```
String.split("\\\")
```

so in your case:

```
String.split("\\\\\\.br\\\\") // extra slash for regex, and String encoded
```

Comment: -1 - you need four slashes, not three.  Three slashes will give you a Java compilation error.

Comment: Actually, he need 5 slashes at the beginning because "." should be escaped too.

Comment: Actually, to match a backslash followed by a dot you need *six* backslashes: four to match the backslash and two to escape the dot.

Comment: Good point - that's what I get for typing w/o the computer in front of me - updating - should only be 5 though, not 6, since the String above is also escaped in the literal.

Comment: No, it has to be six: `"\\\\"` to match the backslash and `"\\."` to match the dot.  And another four at the end to match the trailing backslash.  The way you've got it now--five before and three after--won't even compile.

Comment: Alan - you're correct, updated - and you're right, the 3 slashes will escape the end of the literal

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Pattern.quote()` to escape a string for using as regexp:

```
... = s.split(Pattern.quote("\\.br\\"));
```

Comment: this requires Java 5 by the way

Comment: So does using regexp-based splitting anyway, IIRC.

Comment: @Donal: Regex support, including `split()`, has been around since JDK 1.4.  `quote()` was added in JDK 1.5.

Comment: @Alan: OK, so I was wrong. (I'm working with webservices mostly, and have for quite a while now; they tend to force 1.6 as a minimum.)